# Why milliseconds of the date time 1-1-1970 00:00:00 is in negative?

Tags: java, date, time

While I'm trying to get the time of the date object which represents (1-1-1970 01:00:00), it is returning milliseconds in negative values.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"); Date
 date = sdf.parse("1/1/70 01:00:00");
 System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

The above code will print the negative value. I want to understand how milliseconds will be calculated and how this date is getting a negative value.

Comment: Prints `0` MS for me. Are you asking about `1-1-1970 01:00:00` or `1-1-1970 00:00:00`? If you are interested in how its calculated, dig in the source code which is open source

Comment: First things to check when something date-related is off are always time zone and DST.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @XtremeBaumer have you tried this in IST timezone, as the milliseconds are dependent on time zone

Comment: biziclop sorry i forgot to add the timezone, the above thing raised in IST timezone

Answer (score 4):

Your line `Date date = sdf.parse("1/1/70 01:00:00");` is timezone-sensitive. You're in a GMT+2 timezone, so that date for your timezone is equivalent to 31/12/1969 23:00:00 in GMT.

Comment: yes, thanks. As it is before 1970, it is returning with negative milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

SimpleDateFormat is time zone specific. using dateFormat.parse(timesStamp) will return Date objects for a specific timezone. so it will be ofset from the difference of your local time to GMT.

To fix it try adding `dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` =

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be confusing when you are using the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. The explanation is that your millisecond value is counted from the epoch, and the epoch is defined in UTC, as 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC. So if you’re in a time zone with an offset from UTC, 1970-01-01 00:00 falls on a different point in time, a different moment, a different instant. So depending on whether you are before or after UTC, your millisecond value will be less than or greater than 0.

Things may become clearer when using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This API invites us to make time zone explicit where it is relevant, which is good for avoiding the confusion. Try for example this method:

```
public static void printMilliseconds(ZoneId zone) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1970, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = dateTime.atZone(zone);
    System.out.println("In time zone: " + zdt);
    Instant i = zdt.toInstant();
    System.out.println("As Instant: " + i);
    long milliseconds = i.toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println("Milliseconds since the epoch: " + milliseconds);
}
```

Assuming that your time zone is Asia/Kolkata, let’s pass that zone to the method.

```
    printMilliseconds(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

Then output is:

> ```
> In time zone: 1970-01-01T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
> As Instant: 1969-12-31T18:30:00Z
> Milliseconds since the epoch: -19800000
> ```

The `Instant` prints in UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`), so we can see that the time in India corresponds to five and a half hours before the epoch, which comes out as -19 800 000 milliseconds.

For time zones west of Greenwich we get a positive value. Let’s try America/Mexico_City.

> ```
> In time zone: 1970-01-01T00:00-06:00[America/Mexico_City]
> As Instant: 1970-01-01T06:00:00Z
> Milliseconds since the epoch: 21600000
> ```

And for the sake of completeness, UTC itself. This ought to give 0 (zero). Let’s see.

```
    printMilliseconds(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

> ```
> In time zone: 1970-01-01T00:00Z
> As Instant: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
> Milliseconds since the epoch: 0
> ```

### Don’t use the old classes

The classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are poorly designed, which was a good deal of the explanation for your confusion. I recommend we don’t use them anymore.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thanku. I have understood now, how it is retruning negative milli seconds